# How to change this code to check for another acceptable word of the same length?

Tags: javascript

This code:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var words = fs.readFileSync("words.txt").toString();
words = words.split("\n");

var badLetters = /[gikmsqvwxz]/;
var longestAcceptableWord = "";

for(var testWord of words) {

  if(testWord.length <= longestAcceptableWord.length) {
    continue;
  }

  if(testWord.match(badLetters)) {  continue;  }

  longestAcceptableWord = testWord;

}

console.log(longestAcceptableWord)
```

checks for the longest word in words.txt not including badLetters.
But it's only checking for words longer than the current acceptable one. What happens if there was another acceptable word of the same length? There could be multiple correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array with an empty string as `longestWords`.

The check if the word does not match or the length is smaller than the longest word at index zero,  then `continue`.

Then check if the word is longer than the stored words and assign a new array whith the new longest word or just push the actual word to the array.

BTW, you could take [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) for getting only a wanted boolean value instead of [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

For unwanted whitespace, you could take [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim).

```
let longestWords = [''];

for (let testWord of words) {
    testWord = testWord.trim();
    if (badLetters.test(testWord) || testWord.length < longestWords[0].length) continue;

    if (testWord.length > longestWords[0].length) {
        longestWords = [testWord];
    } else {
        longestWords.push(testWord);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But there's still one thing that bothers me.
When I now run the code:
[ 'polytetrafluoroethylene\r' ]
It prints \r after the word. How to remove that behavior?